# Using python package dependencies from private registries

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitlab, gitlab-ci, setuptools

My employer has a self hosted Gitlab instance, and I have a python package (say `dep`) in one repository. I created a package registry for the same following this [guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/pypi_repository/). I also created a token with `read_api` access, and afterwards I am able to install the package using the following:

```
python -m pip install dep --index-url https://__token__:<personal_access_token>@<gitlab_server_host>/api/v4/projects/<gitlab_project_id>/packages/pypi/simple
```

Now, I have another python package (say `main`) in another repository where I want to use `dep` as a dependency. I tried to specify the following:

```
install_requires =
    <other_packages>
    dep
    <few_more_packages>
```

When I try to install this package, this fails complaining that no version found.

```
python -m pip install -e <path_to_main_package>
```

This is expected as the package is not publicly available on PyPI. Then I tried to use `dependency_links` the following way:

```
dependency_links =
    https://__token__:<personal_access_token>@<gitlab_server_host>/api/v4/projects/<gitlab_project_id>/packages/pypi/simple
```

However, this fails as well complaining the same.

Finally specifying as git dependency seems to work:

```
install_requires =
    <other_packages>
    dep @ git+https://__token__:<personal_access_token>@<gitlab_server_host>/<gitlab_group_id>/<gitlab_project_id>.git#egg=dep&subdirectory=<relative_path_from_repo_root>
    <few_more_packages>
```

But it stores the token unprotected, and that seems wrong since I have to commit `setup.cfg`.

So, my questions are as follows:

1. How can I pass index URL in `setup.cfg`?
2. How can I pass tokens through environmental variables in `setup.cfg`? (Or, some other secure way)

I shall also install `main` in CI and in `Dockerfile` for my requirements, so the solutions has to be a way that do not prompt for me to enter credentials manually. I'd like to be able to pass those as environmental variables as well.

Comment: Note: If it matters, I use `setup.cfg` only and not `setup.py`, and would like to change to `pyproject.toml` when that is finalised.